# Selecting 'edge' records in a sequence of data

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of items which run sequentially by date with both a start and end for each entry:

```
ID | Start            | End
----------------------------------------
1  | 2012-08-20 00:00 | 2012-08-20 23:59 
2  | 2012-08-21 00:00 | 2012-08-21 23:59 
3  | 2012-08-22 00:00 | 2012-08-22 23:59 
4  | 2012-08-23 00:00 | 2012-08-23 23:59 
5  | 2012-08-24 00:00 | 2012-08-24 23:59 
6  | 2012-08-28 00:00 | 2012-08-28 23:59 
7  | 2012-08-29 00:00 | 2012-08-29 23:59 
8  | 2012-08-30 00:00 | 2012-08-30 23:59
```

Note that there are gaps in the data (for a weekend and a bank holiday).  Is it possible to write a query which selects the records at the edges of the gaps?  What I want is a general purpose way to end up with something like this:

```
ID | Start            | End
----------------------------------------
1  | 2012-08-20 09:00 | 2012-08-20 23:59 
2  | 2012-08-21 00:00 | 2012-08-21 23:59 
3  | 2012-08-22 00:00 | 2012-08-22 23:59 
4  | 2012-08-23 00:00 | 2012-08-23 23:59 
5  | 2012-08-24 00:00 | 2012-08-24 17:00 
6  | 2012-08-28 09:00 | 2012-08-28 23:59 
7  | 2012-08-29 00:00 | 2012-08-29 23:59 
8  | 2012-08-30 00:00 | 2012-08-30 17:00
```

Note that the start time of 1 and 6 has been updated, as has the end time of 5 and 8.

In the real database I am forced to used this day by day data layout as it has to retain compatibility with a legacy client, so I can't simply insert the ranges directly.  Also in the real data I could be dealing with several hundred of these records at a time with multiple gaps.

The target platform is SQL2005/2008, though bonus points for solutions which work in SQL2000 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` the get the `lead` and `lag` values and in the column list you can use `datediff` to see if the gap is something other than one day.

```
select T1.ID,
       case
         when datediff(day, Lag.Start, T1.Start) = 1 then T1.Start
         else dateadd(hour, 9, T1.Start)
       end as Start,
       case
         when datediff(day, T1.Start, Lead.Start) = 1 then T1.[End]
         else dateadd(hour, 17, T1.Start)
       end as [End]
from YourTable as T1
  outer apply
    (
      select top(1) T2.Start
      from YourTable as T2
      where T2.Start < T1.Start
      order by T2.Start desc
    ) as Lag(Start)
  outer apply
    (
      select top(1) T2.Start
      from YourTable as T2
      where T2.Start > T1.Start
      order by T2.Start
    ) as Lead(Start)
```

The query above works from SQL Server 2005 even with compatibility SQL Server 2000 (80).

If you find your way to SQL Server 2012 you can use [lead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [lag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256) instead of simulating with an `outer apply`.

```
select T1.ID,
       case
         when datediff(day, lag(T1.Start) over(order by T1.Start), T1.Start) = 1 
         then T1.Start
         else dateadd(hour, 9, T1.Start)
       end as Start,
       case
         when datediff(day, T1.Start, lead(T1.Start) over(order by T1.Start)) = 1 
         then T1.[End]
         else dateadd(hour, 17, T1.Start)
       end as [End]
from YourTable as T1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d904f/3/0)